# Monitor function doesn't show continious change of values

Tags: bugs, documentation, monitoring

**Bug introduced in 10.0 and fixed in 11.0.0**

---

*Mathematica* version: 10.2

```
Monitor[i = 0; While[i < 100, Pause[0.1]; i++]; i, i]
```

The above code is from the documentation of `Monitor`. On my computer, there is no continious change of values showing. What is wrong?

**Update: It turns out that this problem only appears in the documentation page. Still not knowing why**.

Similar behavior [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/96985/two-issues-about-underlined)

Comment: I have MMA 10.2 to and works fine.

Comment: @I_Mariusz I tried again and found odd things. You're right, copy the code into a new notebook, works fine. But if you directly shift+Enter in the documentation page, it doesn't work. Hope that you can try and confirm.

Comment: Yes you are Right in the documentation page,it doesn't work :(

Comment: Not limited to v10.2, same behavior in v9.0.1 in the document page.

Comment: @I_Mariusz Well I am so happy I found a bug:P

Comment: @matheorem.There are more bugs in MMA,problem is to find it.

Comment: Please report this to Wolfram Technical Support and share the case number for future reference.

Comment: @rhermans report it. CASE:3443745

Comment: There is a duplicate of this on this site, but I cannot find it.  I have also reported the problem a few months ago.

Comment: I checked the code in the documentation page for MMA 10.2 and 11.0. While it fails to show the continuous change in 10.2, it works in 11.0.