# Missing old functionality

Tags: compatibility

In a retro mood...

Without a doubt a lot of great new functionality has been added in the latest versions of *Mathematica* (multiple undo anyone:-)!).
Some are covered [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/43631/most-influential-and-or-disrupting-features-introduced-with-new-versions-of-math).

While searching in [Standard Package Compatibility Guide](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/Compatibility/guide/StandardPackageCompatibilityGuide.html), it came into my mind to make a post about old functionality that it is missing from the current versions.

For instance I understand that the amount of information now contained in the [Documentation Center](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/) is enormous, but I really miss the good old *Mathematica* book and the Help Browser of 5.2.

So are there any features, commands, packages and the like which are missing in latest versions of *Mathematica*? Also is there any functionality that, despite all this evolution, has worsened over the years?

Comment: I don't know if Windows does this still, but I made the switch to Linux a while back and I *really* miss the menu "Tile Windows Tall" - because I'm the type of guy to open up 12 untitled notebooks when working out a problem and then condense back down when I have it figured out.

Comment: "I really miss the good old Mathematica book and the Help Browser of 5.2." - so do I. The tree structure of the docs was quite nice.

Comment: The functionality of Mathematica now covers such a wide range that I´m in doubt whether there would be a (single?) Mathematica book to cover this area. At the IMS conference in Prague this January I talked with some people form WRI and was told that there would be a printed documentation of some (key-functions) of Mathematica, e.g. Plot, to figure out the potential of these functions with an enormous number of options.

Comment: @mgamer I think that what most people miss is not a paper book but the easily navigable tree structure where everything has a fixed place.  We do have this (sort of) in version 10 as well, but the UI to access it is not as nice as it was in v5.  Overall, however, this is really a very minor "problem" for me, I've gotten quite used to the new documentation.  And the search feature *was* sorely needed for v5 ...

Comment: I really think this sort of question, while interesting and useful, should be a community wiki.

Comment: @m_goldberg I'd say it should be moved to meta.

Comment: @Kuba. No, it is about _Mathematica_ not about this using this site. But if not a community wiki, I am tempted to vote to close as too broad or too opinion based.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Many old p standard packages have been removed, when their functionality was superseded by new built-in functions.  As far as I know, all of these packages are still available for download.  You can find the download location through the [Standard Package Compatibility Guide](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/Compatibility/guide/StandardPackageCompatibilityGuide.html).  For example, the recently discussed `` Graphics`Colors` `` package is available [here](http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/MathSource/6812/).  The link is mention on [this documentation page](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/Compatibility/tutorial/Graphics/Colors.html).

I remember when the new Documentation Center was introduced, many people (including myself) really missed the old, well-structured Help Browser.  It was easier to navigate, and every page had a *dependable, fixed location*.  That sort of clear-cut hierarchy doesn't seem exist anymore.  The Documentation Center follows the new (well, in 2015 maybe not so new) trend of using search instead of table of contents.  Each page is accessible through multiple (an in my probably wrong impression, sometimes *zero*) routes ... I'm no longer confident that there is a dependable fixed location for every page ...

You can see all the different ways to get to a documentation page at the top (sometimes this seems to be missing ...)

[image]

In response to all the complaints, WRI included the Virtual Book in one of the 6.0.x point releases, if I remember well.  It was simple a table of contents.  There was also the Function Navigator.  Even though I missed the old v5 Help Browser, I only used he Virtual Book rarely.  I did find it useful for finding certain advanced tutorials though, or at least remembering their precise location without having to remember fickle search terms to get to them:

[image]

In version 10, the button for the Virtual Book and Function Navigator were removed.  The Virtual Book is now converted into a standard page in the Documentation Center, but the full hierarchical table of context is no longer visible on a single page, which is slightly frustrating.  See this post for details:

- [Where is the "Function Navigator" and "Virtual Book" gone?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/54781/where-is-the-function-navigator-and-virtual-book-gone)

The *first* location displayed on top of most function pages refers to the location within this table of contents.

The old Help Browser is still included as a function component to support old packages that use the old help system.  It does not include the main documentation.  You can bring it up using e.g. `HelpBrowserLookup["AddOns", "foo"]` or by opening the documentation old packages: go to Documentation Center, at the bottom click Add-Ons to bring up the list of installed add-ons, and click an add-on to get to its documentation.

[image]

Comment: I don't miss the old help browser at all. I *live* in the new help system. But I know my way around. My main gripe is that there is currently no real, easily accessible way for new learners to start learning Mathematica like the first 100 pages or so of the old paper manual did. And there are plenty of 'manual bugs' like '@' in search referring to the nearly useless `Prefix` page, and the very misleading description of the *Form functions as 'only influencing printing, but not calculation'. Both of these errors (and others) have existed for ages, are well known, but still exist.

Comment: @Sjoerd At the bottom of the front page there's a Common How-tos link.  It looks like it's good for new users.  But it's not very noticeable.  I think Mathematica might give some hints on what to read when newly installed, but that wouldn't be shown in a school computer lab where many people use it ...

Comment: Thanks for the comments and the very helpful reply. As a small example  of worse functionality over the years compare the results in the comment of  Oleksandr R. here http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/97073/bad-performance-of-integrate-and-wolframalpha-for-an-integral-of-bessel-functi and the post http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/96985/two-issues-about-underlined and here http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/96740/monitor-function-doesnt-show-continious-change-of-values

Comment: It seems `HelpBrowserLookup` and `HelpBrowserNotebook` are defunct in V13, maybe earlier.

Comment: @MichaelE2 Much earlier, but I forgot which version. I'd guess 12, when they added 64-bit support on Mac.