# Bad performance of Integrate (and WolframAlpha) for an Integral of Bessel function of the first kind: Version 11 edit

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, special-functions

**Version 11 Edit**

The issue still remains:

```
Integrate[BesselJ[0, x], {x, 0, ∞}] // Timing
(* {29.8125, 1} *)

$Version
```

### (* "11.3.0 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (March 7, 2018)" *)

**Original post**

The following returns unevaluated in [WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Integrate%5BBeselJ%5B0%2Cx%5D%2C%7Bx%2C0%2CInfinity%7D%5D).
Also in my machine Mathematica needs quite a lot of time to compute it.

```
In[720]:= Integrate[BesselJ[0, x], {x, 0, \[Infinity]}] // Timing
Out[720]= {26.520170, 1}
```

I am puzzled because I thought such integrals are well tabulated in Mathematica.

At least the numerical integration is performed very quickly.

```
In[721]:= NIntegrate[BesselJ[0, x], {x, 0, \[Infinity]}] // Timing
Out[721]= {0.826805, 1.}
```

Any ideas about this performance of Mathematica and WolframAlpha?

**EDIT**

As  *J. M. is back* suggested the following gives the result almost immediately

```
In[734]:= LaplaceTransform[BesselJ[0, t], t, s] /. s -> 0 // Timing
Out[734]= {0., 1}
```

For me the poor behavior of Integrate here still remains. What is even worse are the differences between the result of Mathematica and WolframAlpha.

```
In[761]:= LaplaceTransform[BesselJ[0, t], t, s]
Out[761]= 1/Sqrt[1 + s^2]
```

whereas WolframAlpha returns

```
1/(sqrt(1+1/s^2) s)
```

So you have to type

```
Limit[1/(sqrt(1+1/s^2) s),s->0]
```

in order to get finally 1.

**EDIT 2**

```
In[2]:= Quit[]

In[1]:= Integrate[BesselJ[0, x], {x, 0, \[Infinity]}, 
  GenerateConditions -> False] // Timing
Out[1]= {26.301769, 1}

In[2]:= Quit[]

In[1]:= Integrate[BesselJ[n, x], {x, 0, \[Infinity]}, 
  GenerateConditions -> False] // Timing
Out[1]= {0.109201, 1}

In[2]:= Quit[]

In[1]:= Integrate[BesselJ[n, x], {x, 0, \[Infinity]}, 
  GenerateConditions -> True] // Timing
Out[1]= {8.049652, ConditionalExpression[1, Re[n] > -1]}
```

Compare the times 8.049652 (with `n` and `GenerateConditions->True` !) and 26.301769 (with `n=0`).

Rather funny:-)!

**EDIT 3**
Even more weird...

```
In[2]:= Quit[]

In[1]:= Integrate[BesselJ[n, x], {x, 0, \[Infinity]}, 
  Assumptions -> n > 0] // Timing
Out[1]= {22.417344, 1}
```

Compare the times of `Assumptions` and `GenerateConditions->True`.

**EDIT 4**

Apparently something goes very wrong. With a clear kernel I got

```
Table[Timing[Integrate[BesselJ[0, x], {x, 0, Infinity}]], {i, 1, 10}]
Table[Timing[Integrate[BesselJ[1, x], {x, 0, Infinity}]], {i, 1, 10}]
Table[Timing[Integrate[BesselJ[2, x], {x, 0, Infinity}]], {i, 1, 10}]
Table[Timing[Integrate[BesselJ[3, x], {x, 0, Infinity}]], {i, 1, 10}]
```

[image: Results]

For `m >= 4` Mathematica gives the 1 for m odd (same behavior as for m=3). For m even also gives 1 in all cases but needs more than 20 sec per average to evaluate the integral.

I cannot find a reason to explain this behavior which other more experienced users have called it buggy. I think Mathematica makes use of this [reference](http://The%20evaluation%20of%20integrals%20of%20Bessel%20functions%20via%20G-function%20identities). So apparently something is treated differently for n even.

**EDIT 5**
 I_Mariusz pointed out a workaround. I added here in order to show its performance (if any) in `Timing` (and since on one hand our comments had misprints and on the other I did not know that `Integrate` can be compiled).

With a clear kernel I got:

```
int = Compile[{{x, _Real}}, 
   Integrate[BesselJ[0, x], {x, 0, Infinity}, 
    GenerateConditions -> False]];

Table[int[x] // Quiet // Timing, {10}]
```

> {{26.254968, 1}, {24.897760, 1}, {24.897760, 1}, {20.046128,    1},
>   {0.046800, 1}, {0.046800, 1}, {0.062400, 1}, {0.062400,    1},
>   {0.062400, 1}, {0.062400, 1}}

At least now we get 1's in the whole loop!

Comment: As a side remark SageMath returns a rather complicated expression with limits and other special functions while Maple online returns 1 almost immediately http://maplecloud.maplesoft.com/application.jsp?appId=15195116.

Comment: If you want it quick: `LaplaceTransform[BesselJ[0, t], t, s] /. s -> 0`

Comment: Thanks. But the issue remains. Why Mathematica needs such a long time for integral like this? Also, why WolframAlpha completely fails, whereas Maple Online Calculator gives the correct almost immediately? Integrals like this should be tabulated or not? There not any parameters. I think the performance is rather poor.

Comment: Hard to say; after all, we don't know what actually happens inside. Probably it is trying to derive that known result from a more general result actually known by *Mathematica*.

Comment: A novice user of Mathematica might not know (I am not but I did not think about it) `LaplaceTransform[BesselJ[0, t], t, s] /. s -> 0`. He will use `Integrate[BesselJ[0, x], {x, 0, \[Infinity]}]` and may compare it with the performance of Maple...

Comment: @ J. M. is back: I just show your comment. I guess you are right but still the performance is poor  here.

Comment: Version 5.2 takes 1.9 seconds; version 7, 0.5 seconds; version 8, 2.1 seconds; version 9, 5.1 seconds. After the result is produced for the first time, it is cached and appears instantaneously on subsequent requests. If the situation is much worse in *Mathematica* 10, I believe you ought to file this with WRI as a performance regression bug.

Comment: Good old Mathematica 5.2:-)! Thanks for the comment and the advice.

Comment: For another timing, try `Simplify[Integrate[BesselJ[n, x], {x, 0, \[Infinity]}, GenerateConditions -> True], n > -1] // Timing`

Comment: Aside from timing, the second attempt at evaluating the integral fails: http://i.stack.imgur.com/dWBPV.png -- that strikes me as a bug.

Comment: @ Michael E2  I add an Edit which supports your idea.

Comment: For more speed use `Compile`. int = Compile[{{x, _Real}}, 
  Integrate[BesselJ[0, x], {x, 0, \[Infinity]}, 
   GenerateConditions -> False]]; int[x] // Quiet // Timing.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Actually your code contained misprints. I think you mean: `int[x_] = 
  Compile[{{x, _Real}}, 
   Integrate[BesselJ[0, x], {x, 0, Infinity}, 
    GenerateConditions -> False]];

int[x] // Quiet // Timing`

Comment: In any case it is amazing. I did not know for this usage of `Compile`. `Integrate` can be compiled? I do not see it here (I think so) http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1096/list-of-compilable-functions

Comment: @dimitris I don't think that the `Compile` trick actually works. What it does is simply to execute the uncompiled code `Integrate[BesselJ[0,x],{x,0,Infinity},GenerateConditions->False]` every time. This happens because `int` is called with a symbolic argument `x` so `Compile` here is simply irrelevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is not a answer but can serve as a summary of the useful workarounds. Still we do not have a rigorous explanation of the buggy (?) behavior.

Since

```
Integrate[BesselJ[0, x], {x, 0, \[Infinity]}] // Timing
(*{27.112974, 1}*)
```

J. M. is back suggested the following which gives the result almost immediately.

```
LaplaceTransform[BesselJ[0, t], t, s] /. s -> 0 // Timing
(*{0., 1}*)
```

In WolframAlpha we will get `1/(sqrt(1+1/s^2) s)` from the `LaplaceTransform` so we need in addition `Limit[1/(sqrt(1+1/s^2) s),s->0]`.

Integration with generic `n` gives the correct result but still the time is very large.

```
Integrate[BesselJ[n, x], {x, 0, \[Infinity]}] // Timing
 (*{11.731275, ConditionalExpression[1, Re[n] > -1]}*)

Integrate[BesselJ[n, x], {x, 0, \[Infinity]}, 
  Assumptions -> n \[Element] Reals] // Timing
 (*{29.780591, ConditionalExpression[1, n > -1]}*)
```

As a workaround we can ignore the conditions

```
ClearSystemCache[]
Integrate[BesselJ[n, x], {x, 0, \[Infinity]}, 
  GenerateConditions -> False] // Timing
(*{0.093601, 1}*)
```

or more rigorous (after B. Hanlon)

```
 Simplify[Integrate[BesselJ[n, x], {x, 0, \[Infinity]}, GenerateConditions -> True], n > -1] // Timing
 (*{11.778075, 1}*)
```

Another interesting workaround is by I_Mariusz

```
int = Compile[{{x, _Real}}, 
   Integrate[BesselJ[0, x], {x, 0, Infinity}, 
    GenerateConditions -> False]];

Table[int[x] // Quiet // Timing, {10}]
```

> {{26.254968, 1}, {24.897760, 1}, {24.897760, 1}, {20.046128, 1},
>   {0.046800, 1}, {0.046800, 1}, {0.062400, 1}, {0.062400, 1},
>   {0.062400,1}, {0.062400, 1}}

Notice that

```
Table[Timing[Integrate[BesselJ[0, x], {x, 0, Infinity}]], {i, 1, 10}]
```

returns only the first three iterations corrected.

Comment: The Laplace route can be used for arbitrary order.

Comment: Of course! I should have added it!